# Concatenating collections while retaining bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, plunker

I have two arrays in my controller and a third array which is formed by concatenating the first two arrays.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var MainController = app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.dogs = ['Beagle', 'Poodle', 'Boxer'];
  $scope.cats = ['Maine Coon', 'Ragdoll', 'Bengal'];
  $scope.pets = $scope.dogs.concat($scope.cats);

  $scope.createDog = function() {
    $scope.dogs.push('Rottweiler');
  };
});
```

I then output all this data using `ng-repeat`.

```
<h3>Dogs ({{dogs.length}})</h3>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">{{dog}}</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="createDog()">Add a dog</button>
<hr>
<h3>Cats ({{cats.length}})</h3>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="cat in cats">{{cat}}</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h3>Pets ({{pets.length}})</h3>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="pet in pets">{{pet}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I click the button and add a dog to the `$scope.dogs` array, the list of pets never gets updated.

[Here's the code on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WLXv0C?p=preview)

How can I concat two collections of objects while preserving angular's bindings so that the pets will update?

Comment: One way of doing this is to use `$watch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this, by defining $scope.pets as a function, so it's an expression and updates when ever a used $scope variable within is being updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/6DyKeN?p=preview

```
$scope.pets = function() {
    return $scope.dogs.concat($scope.cats);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

For pets to be updated change your JS function to,

```
$scope.createDog = function() {
   $scope.dogs.push('Rottweiler');
   $scope.pets = $scope.dogs.concat($scope.cats);
```

};

Since you have pushed the same name ie.;'Rottweiler'. It will not get rendered by ng-repeat on the screen due to duplicates creation, so use

For dogs,

```
<li ng-repeat="dog in dogs track by $index">{{dog}}</li>
```

For Pets,

```
<li ng-repeat="pet in pets track by $index">{{pet}}</li>
```